# Changing regex "^[^<>]+$" by Html.Encode in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need to allow symbols `<` `>` but also prevent XSS attacks, so I'm trying to use `HTML.Encode()` method:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Text, 15, 5,
 new { placeholder = ReviewResources.ReviewPlaceholder, data_val = "true",
 data_val_regex=ReviewResources.IllegalSymbolsMessage,
 data_val_regex_pattern="^[^<>]+$"}
```

Changing for:

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => @Html.Encode(Model.Text), 15, 5,
 new { placeholder = ReviewResources.ReviewPlaceholder, data_val = "true"}
```

But I'm getting an exception:

```
 {"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, 
single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."}
```

How to use correctly encoding from `<` to `&lt;` and et cetera?

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do better.  You need to allow angle brackets for what purpose?

Comment: i just needed them for "=>"symbols or math operations (a>b)